# transactional email totals

Tags: magento-1.9, email, transactional-mail, format

Can any tell me how to format the totals at the bottom  of the transactional emails... I want them to be to the far right.
If I view the mail in the browser the totals are to the left.

[image: email]

Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 1):

Since you're currently using the RWD Magento theme, I would suggest making a minor theme override with a couple changes. This involves both an update to the rwd sales.xml layout for `<sales_email_order_items>` (and potentially any other transactional email you wish to change). It also involves a small CSS update.

If you look at `<root>/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/sales.xml`, you can find several XML section related to the email order totals. `sales_email_order_items`, `sales_email_order_invoice_items`, and so on.

```xml
<!--
Email layouts section
-->
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="core/template" name="order_totals_wrapper" as="order_totals" template="email/order/totals/wrapper.phtml">
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

Note these lines:

```
<action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
<action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
```

These are setting the text alignments of the various totals segments.

As you also identified, the `order_totals_wrapper` block also has a style applied which right justifies the totals table. The source SCSS files are located at `<root>/skin/frontend/rwd/default/scss/email-inline.scss` via the `.padding-totals` class. However, this file is ultimately inherited from the core theme at `<root>/skin/frontend/base/default/css/email-inline.css`.

---

Now for the fix. We need to create a new theme which inherits from rwd. This will allow us to create targeted overrides but use the rwd theme at the core.

Create a new directory under `<core>/app/design/frontend/<uniquename>`. "uniquename" will be your new theme. Create the file `<core>/app/design/frontend/<uniquename>/default/etc/theme.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

This file tells the theme to inherit directly from the `rwd/default` theme. (You might want to change this to `rwd/enterprise` if you are using Enterprise Magento.)

Now create `<root>/app/design/frontend/<uniquename>/default/layout/local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <sales_email_order_items>
        <reference name="order_totals">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="left" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="left" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
        </reference>
    </sales_email_order_items>
</layout>
```

These directive will reset the value and label css values to `align="left"`.

Copy the above `email-inline.css` file to:

`<root>/skin/frontend/<uniquename>/default/css/email-inline.css`

In this file, locate the `.padding-totals` directive and update it to:

```css
.padding-totals {
  padding: 20px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Finally, you will need to apply your new theme to Magento. Within the `Admin > System > Configuration > Design > Package` change the "Current Package Name" to `<uniquename>`, save, and flush the cache. Your theme overrides should now take over and the email css changes should be live.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the answer but I can't find the .LESS files. I should have stated I am using Magento CE 1.9.3.3

Comment: Ah - well that changes things a bit. Let me rewrite the answer. Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: I think i have just found it... I am using rwd. I have just found /home/reecesafetyco/public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/email/order/totals/wrapper.phtm and added style="float:right; to the td

Comment: I wouldn't recommend editing core template files directly. I'm about to update my answer.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Sorry for the delay. I have just applied your fix and it worked like a charm. Well describe and easy to follow instructions. A great help. Thank you so much.

Comment: HI Again, Sorry I have just checked again after removing the edit to the wrapper.html file and the fix detailled above doesn't seem to have had any impact.